# Kik Card - Can I import/require the Kik.js file instead?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, kik

Building out a mobile web app, targeting Kik. Their docs tell you to add the Kik.js file directly to your HTML like so:

```
<!-- simply include this script in your webpage -->
<script src="http://cdn.kik.com/kik/2.3.6/kik.js"></script>
```

But as any front-end developer who has worked on production sites/apps in the last 5 years knows, it's best to bundle your code together using some sort of tool (personally I'm using Webpack) to cut down on requests.

Is there a better way for me to import the Kik code, making better use of tools like NPM, or ES6's `import` statements? Their method of just dropping that script tag in there just feels very jQuery circa 2009, and if there is a better approach out there I would like to investigate/try it.

Answer (score 1):

So after beautifying this code, and poking around in it, it looks like that it takes and exports a free global so that you can use. Long story short its not like some modules which support UMD (CommonJS, AMD, Script Tag) loading.

However I did stumble across what looks to be a [github repo](https://github.com/kikinteractive) that is maintained by Kik that might have some importable scripts you can provide.

Otherwise I stick the script in an 'assets' file and then manually import it into my entry file so webpack can pick it up.